# What is Connect.RegisterUser in facebook developer toolkit

Tags: c#, facebook

How can i link my application's account to facebook? This is the code :-

```
BrowserSession    _browserSession = new BrowserSession(ApplicationKey, new Enums.ExtendedPermissions[] { Enums.ExtendedPermissions.email, Enums.ExtendedPermissions.manage_mailbox, Enums.ExtendedPermissions.read_mailbox,
                Enums.ExtendedPermissions.status_update, Enums.ExtendedPermissions.share_item, Enums.ExtendedPermissions.offline_access});

                Connect connect = new Connect(_browserSession);
                connect.RegisterUsersAsync(List<ConnectAccountMap>);
```

As you can see connect.RegisterUsersAsync requires List of ConnectAccountMap type. How do i get those ConnectAccountMaps? The properties of ConnectAccountMap are EmailAddress, AccountId and AccountUrl. But how do i get those parameters?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you fetched the data like EmailAddress already?

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro :- No I didn't fetch. Do i need to fetch it? Facebook doesn't give real email address. It only gives proxied email address which means you get something like `asasdasa82348932903@facebook.com`.

Comment: @Ankit See i haven't used Toolkit, instead i write all my code myself.But steps remain the same as mentioned in Documentation. when you Authorize your application with those extended permissions you get an Authorization key in exchange of that key you get an Session key use that session key to Fetch Email and other information. And Facebook DO gives REAL Email id just don't spam him.

Comment: And Facebook Developer toolkit has been depricated.. try using Facebook C# SDK http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro :- I do have the session key, but somehow can't find the method to retrieve email from it. And what do you mean by WRITTEN ALL CODE MYSELF? You probably mean you must have written javascript by hand. Didn't you? But still you are using the same facebook functions. Aren't you?

Comment: Its just the difference of Serialization.. what i have written uses JavaScriptSerializer.. Facebook Toolkit Uses Json Serializer By Nikhil Kothari. And i havent use javascript a bit .. its all done by Graph API. Its just the matter of convenience.. it was my project so had to write all my code myself. Dont get overwhelmed by it. I can show you how to get user information my way. I havent used toolkits so Sorry :(..see someone might else answer your query. :)

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro :- Probably i should use what other people are using rather than trying to reinvent the wheel for nothing. I will wait for someone else :).

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro :- Also have a look at this post which will tell you exactly what i was referring to :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908478/get-user-email-using-facebook-toolkit. Facebook doesn't give real email address if user has his privacy settings set. But i NEED the email address.

Comment: @Ankit It was not possible Previously but now requesting the "email" Extended Permission entitles you to get his primary email address. I myself checked it by changing the privacy setting to only me.. stll my website was getting the real email.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i am answering my own question. I did try Facebook C# SDK and didn't get it work. I studied the sample and changed the appId and was even successfull in login in but could not make it to work. This function failed

```
 [ScriptableMember]
        public void LoggedIn(string uri) //string sessionKey, string sessionSecret, int expires, string userId, string allowedPermissions)
        {
            FacebookAuthenticationResult authResult;
            if (FacebookAuthenticationResult.TryParse(uri, out authResult))
            {
                fbApp.Session = authResult.ToSession();
                loginSucceeded();
            }
            else
            {
                failedLogin();
            }
        }
```

The line `FacebookAuthenticationResult.TryParse` kept failing and i was frustrated like anything. Finally i made it work using Facebook Developer Toolkit V3.1 itself.

This query works just fine :-

```
 _fb.Fql.QueryAsync("SELECT email FROM user WHERE uid=" + u.uid, new Fql.QueryCallback((str, obj, exc) => {

                        Debug.WriteLine(str);

                    }), null);
```

Offcourse your application should ask for extended permissions of email. A query is compulsorily needed because in `user` object of Facebook there is no property which can fetch you the real email address. You can if you want to retrieve proxied_email but most of the case that isn't what you are always looking for and hence the query ! You will get the xml which you can easily parse it using Linq To Xml or traditional Xml c# classes. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Old Facebook Developer Toolkit here is a good example to start with.

http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=45825

Other wise for new C# SDK consider having a look at

http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20Examples&referringTitle=Documentation

Hope it may help.

And FYI as mentioned here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/connect.registerUsers

connect.register user has been deprecated.